# Write as a power series

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, power-series

I've got to write $\sum_{n=1000}^{\infty} i^{n}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{n!}$ as a power series. However in my mind isn't it already a power series, I don't really understand what the question is asking.

I started by putting it in the form $\sum_{n=1000}^{\infty} a_n(z-a)^{2n-1}$ where a=0 and $a_n= \frac{i^{n}}{n!}$ and stated its equal to that when $a_n$=0 for all n<1999, $a_n$=1 for all odd n>1999 and $a_n$=0 for all even n>1999, but this doesn't seem write at all so i've no idea where to go from here

Comment: I definitely agree -- It already is a power series.

Comment: The question literally says 'write that as a power series' i don't get why it isn't one already and what i'm supposed to write it as

Comment: Maybe that the starting point for  a series is defined as $n=0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that whoever created that problem wants you to provide this answer: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$, with$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac{i^{\frac{n+1}2}}{\left(\frac{n+1}2\right)!}&\text{ if $n$ odd and greater than }1998\\0&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yeah that's what it's looking like, would it not be $\frac{i^{n}}{n!}$ though?

Comment: No. The first term of your original series is $\frac{i^{1000}}{1\,000!}z^{1\,999}$. So, if $n=1\,999$, the exponent of $i$ must be $\frac{1\,999+1}2$.

Comment: Did you use product of nth roots of Unity??

Answer (score 0):

I would get rid of the $i$s like this:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1000}^{\infty} i^{n}\frac{z^{2n-1}}{n!}
&=\sum_{n=250}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^3 i^{4n+k}\frac{z^{2(4n+k)-1}}{(4n+k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 \sum_{n=250}^{\infty}i^{4n+k}\frac{z^{8n+2k-1}}{(4n+k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\sum_{n=250}^{\infty}i^{4n}\frac{z^{8n+2k-1}}{(4n+k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k\sum_{n=250}^{\infty}\frac{z^{8n+2k-1}}{(4n+k)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^3 i^ks_{4n+k}(z)
\qquad\text{where } s_m(z)=\sum_{n=250}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2m-1}}{m!}\\
&=s_{4n}(z)+is_{4n+1}(z)-s_{4n+2}(z)-is_{4n+3}(z)\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: It's a complex power series so i don't believe you're trying to remove the $i$'s

Comment: I believe that I'm trying to remove the $i$'s.